# How do I create a shortcut to import most used python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am looking for a way to automatically (or as a shortcut) import a set of python modules in a jupyter notebook so that I don't have to import them every time I create a new notebook

I am finding it very repetitive to import these modules to every notebook. The closest thing I could think here is creating a python file and importing that as a module, but I am looking for something more flexible in Jupyter-notebook

```
# Example Code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

What could be an easy way to import these long list of modules? as I am finding myself repeating the whole set of modules in every notebook.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a file `frequently_imported_modules.py` where you have literally only the imports you use frequently and then import all these in your new script like so:

```
from frequently_imported_modules import *
```

Whether this is a good practice? I don't think so.

Comment: I think this is the only resort as of now. I haven't even found any jupyter extensions to do it for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you having the notebook locally?

Comment: For the current example, yes.